# Fortran debugger for Mac OS X

Tags: macos, debugging, fortran

Can anyone recommend a good Fortran debugger for the mac (other than installing gdb, etc, via fink or macports)?

Comment: You don't need to use fink or macports to get gdb - if you install Apple's Xcode developer tools, you'll get working versions of gcc and gdb.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the Intel Fortran Compiler for Mac integrates with Xcode and thereby gives you source level (GUI) debugging: http://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-compilers/

Also it looks like you can get Xcode plug-ins for `gfortran`: http://www.macresearch.org/xcode_tutorial_fortran_only_projects

Answer (score 1):

With the IDB for Mac only providing a command-line interface, and Xcode only being capable of debugging simple structured Fortran programs with no support of MODULEs, maybe you can try TotalView.